# .NET Core Docker Image doesn't seem to have node.js installed

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project and I want to containerize it using Docker. The process of creating/building images seems to be ok but when the ASP.NET app is running inside the container I can see some exception messages (AggregateException) in the console:

```js
Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node process.
```

It seems that it can't find Node from the PATH but I have added a command to make sure node.js will be installed.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS Base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build

# Restore dotnet before build to allow for caching
WORKDIR /
COPY MyProject.Common/MyProject.Common.csproj /src/MyProject.Common/
COPY MyProject.Data/MyProject.Data.csproj /src/MyProject.Data/
COPY MyProject.DomainClasses/MyProject.DomainClasses.csproj /src/MyProject.DomainClasses/
COPY MyProject.Services/MyProject.Services.csproj /src/MyProject.Services/
COPY MyProject.Tests/MyProject.Tests.csproj /src/MyProject.Tests/
COPY MyProject.ViewModel/MyProject.ViewModel.csproj /src/MyProject.ViewModel/
COPY MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj /src/MyProject.Web/

RUN dotnet restore /src/MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj

# Copy source files and build
COPY . /src

RUN dotnet build /src/MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj --no-restore -c Release
RUN dotnet publish /src/MyProject.Web/MyProject.Web.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app

# Copy compiled app to runtime container
FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build /app .

RUN npm install

CMD ["dotnet", "MyProject.Web.dll"]
```

**PS**: Dockerfile is inside `MyProject.Web` project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was incorrect value for an environment variable in `docker-compose` file, It was using the `Development` value for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment because I had this code inside my Startup class:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
    }
```

I changed it to `Production` now it works perfectly fine:

```
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```